# Scheme racket question about finding vowels in str

Tags: racket

I tried to write a code about get-vowels and its running 100% but I'm trying to show these 4 output,
I just want to show these 4 output as well and I couldn't find a solution.

```
> (define vowels (string->list "aeiouyæøå"))
> (define (vowel? c)
  (member c vowels))
> (define (filter p xs)
  (define (more) (filter p (cdr xs)))
  (cond
    ((null? xs)    '())
    ((p (car xs))  (cons (car xs) (more)))
    (else          (more))))
> (define (count-vowels s)
  (length (filter vowel? (string->list s))))
> (display (count-vowels "foobarbaz"))
4
```

example:
output:
4
"ooaa"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't name a procedure `filter`, it clashes with a built-in procedure that does *exactly the thing* that you intend. In fact, you just need to delete your `filter` implementation and it'll work :)

```
(define vowels (string->list "aeiouyæøå"))

(define (vowel? c)
  (member c vowels))

(define (count-vowels s)
  (length (filter vowel? (string->list s))))

; there's a bit of code duplication here, you could
; refactor it if you want, to avoid repeating yourself    
(define (extract-vowels s)
  (list->string (filter vowel? (string->list s))))

(count-vowels "foobarbaz")
=> 4

(extract-vowels "foobarbaz")
=> "ooaa"
```

Comment: okay but how can I show the strings as well like output = "ooaa"

Comment: @BoraNurgören well, then we need a new procedure for it :) . Remember: compose, reuse whenever possible; I just updated my answer.